# Android - Jetpack Compose - ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

build.gradle:

```
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4-alpha03")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.1.0-alpha06")
```

My androidTest class:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun testUI() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        AppTheme {
            SomeComposeUI(
                
            )
        }
    }
    composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.apply)
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getString(R.string.apply)
    
}
```

The issue I'm having is that `composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.apply)` or `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getString(R.string.apply)` are always returning `Method threw 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException'` exception.

I've tried the latest alpha versions and the latest stable versions but with no luck. I've even tried the compose project which you can import in android studio and that has the same error.

Notes:

- Building with SDK 31.
- Testing on SDK 31 device (Same issue with any SDK device).
- AGP 7.0.2 - Gradle 7.2

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with my project and the android project you can't use `composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.apply)` whilst the debugger is attached in most scenarios.

Running without the debugger doesn't have the same issue so makes development a touch harder, but at least I have a fix.